# Why I'm getting res is not defined error using i81n for node JS express and cannot switch between languages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm new to Node JS, I have problem with it using localization i18n for Node JS and express also I'm using ejs as my view engine..

My locals files like this:

en.json

```
{
   "test": "this is a test",
}
```

fr.json

```
{
   "test": "c'est un test",
}
```

My server.js simply like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const i18n = require('i18n');

i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en', 'fr'], 
    directory: __dirname + '/locales', 
    defaultLocale: 'en', 
    cookie: 'lang',
});

app.use(i18n.init);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

My index.ejs is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<%= res.locale %>">

   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Test App</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h1><%= res.__('test') %></h1>     
   </body>

</html>
```

Finally, my express server is properly running without localization.

Now after setting it up for localization and running it again I got those errors!

1. res is not defined in `<html lang="<%= res.locale %>">`
2. res is not defined in `<h1><%= res.__('test') %></h1>`

If I try to remove the `res.` it's working however the language is not changing!

Also tried to pass `res` like this:

```
res.render('test', {abc: res.__('test')});
```

And changed the index.js like this:

```
<html lang="<%= abc%>">
```

But still not working, maybe yes the error is gone like prevoius tries but language still not switching.

Besides the only way I found to switch the language is to do `locales: ['fr']` or `locales: ['en']` which is I don't think it's right way.

So how to rectify this problem and how can I hardcode shifting between the langauges like by changing `defaultLocale: 'fr'` or `i18n.setLocale('fr')` ?

Comment: According to the [`res.render` docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) you have to pass in the data you want to have access to as the second argument to the `render` call.

Comment: @Palladium02 I tried to pass it, it's not working but if I pass another data, it works but not the localization one

Comment: How are you passing/trying to pass the data to `.render` your given code snippets do not show that.

Comment: @Palladium02 I tired like this something like this `res.render('test', {name: res.__('test')} );`

Comment: Well then you should be able to use it like so `<%= name %>`. When doing that what is the error you are running into (or does that even work?).

Comment: @Palladium02 I did its like any other try the error maybe gone but still the language is not switching or lets say its not reading the second language file which I feel it's not the right approach